# Shortest path algorithm for longest path problem?

Tags: graphs

A central insight of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm is that every subpath of the shortest path is also the shortest path of the subgraph. But is that also true for the longest path? In particular, I want to find the longest path of a DAG, and I don't know if it's completely different. My problem is to find the longest ascending sequence of pairs (x_i,y_i), and if I arrange them in a graph with a direction e.g. from (3,4) to (5,8) then the longest path would be the answer if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: The property is not verified. As a simple example, take a graph of three nodes and three edges of equal length. The longest path from B to C (BAC) is not a subpath of the path from A to C (ABC).